# How to store a long string into JDBC?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I just want to put a long plain text of String into a database, SQLite using Java.

Is there anyways that I can do this?

I am really new to SQL things and despite some researches, I still don't even get how to start creating a Table for **just one long string.**

Comment: What means "long plain text" in your case? In JPA is something like [`@Lob`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html) annotation, maybe it's all what you need.

Comment: just a string with long data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out the SQLite3 documentation [here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Then just create a single table with single TEXT attribute. Then just execute your SQL:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO table (Word) VALUES('Your long string')");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how should I create the table?

Comment: Have you looked at any examples before posting a question here? Google is your bestfriend :)
Check this out: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-create-table/